# Create variable from props and reuse in code block with Styled Components?

Tags: styled-components

Ive got a basic styled component working. When the prop `isHere` is passed then the background is `blue`.

```
const Item = styled.ul`
  ${props => console.log(props.theme.colorGroupSelected)};
  ${props => (props.isHere ? `background:` + 'blue' : null)};
`;
```

Instead of `blue` I need to use the colour `colorGroupSelected` from my theme but I cant get it to work, I keep getting a syntax error.

```
    const Item = styled.ul`
      ${props => (props.isHere ? `background:` + props => props.theme.colorGroupSelected : null)};
    `;
```

My code is getting quite hard to read. Is it possible to destructure a variable within a styled block? Something like this:

```
 ${const colorGroupSelected = (props => return props.theme.colorGroupSelected)};

 ${props => (props.isHere ? `background:` + colorGroupSelected : null)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but doesn't destructure the variable:

```
 ${props => (props.isHere ? `background:` + props.theme.colorGroupSelected : null)};
```